# How do I completely remove all git commits including fetched objects?

Tags: git, svn, fetch

I want to git svn fetch again when testing. because first time I ran it, everything is working as expecetd, except that I missed a few names in 
`--authors-file`, so some authors ended up without having full name in git log, then I added missing names again, and cleared all the commits, then run `git svn fetch` again, but it did not fetch the data and creates commits again this time, it finishes without error and there is not commits created.

Why the following method does not work?

```
git update-ref -d HEAD
git co --orphan mybranch
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
# objects did not go away, it seems they are packed instead
# now git svn fetch again, it uses existing data  in .git/objects
```

Comment: Just `rm -rf` the entire repository, `mkdir` new empty repository, and start over. Save the one map file before `rm -rf`-ing of course.

Comment: I have other branches in the repo which are working fine and were retrieved from different svn directories, which were not committed, I do not want to delete the whole repo and start again.

Comment: Ah. Well, I'd recommend not trying to *delete* `HEAD`, but other than "blow away the repository" I have no idea where the svn importers might secrete items. Deleting branch and tag names it may have created would be important. Clearing out objects (`git gc`) might be useful to help with disk space and subsequent re-import time but is likely ultimately irrelevant.